# most efficient mysql query construction for multiple 0..N elements

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I have the following problem (dumb example)

User -> hasMany(Trousers)

User -> hasMany(Shirts)

Is it possible in one single query to retrieve all User/Trouser User/Shirt couples ? I know it's possible with an union all but fields in Trousers and Shirts table differs.

The database structure seems odd but it cannot be modified as it'll imply too many code refactoring.

Comment: `one-to-many` => `JOIN`, not `UNION`.

Comment: yeah but if both joined table are 0..N and I want to retrieve user whether he have trousers OR shirt OR both, should I just use 2 left outer ? my result will be weird as the selected line will have fields from user/trouser/shirt table